# How can I change a list of strings into CSV in Python?

Tags: python

#### Example strings:

```
uji708
uhodih
utus29
agamu4
azi340
ekon62
```

I need to change them into CSV list like this:

```
uji708,uhodih,utus29,  
agamu4,azi340,ekon62,
```

My code so far:

```
email = 'mail_list.txt'
handle = open(email)

for line in handle:
    try:
        email = line.split()[0].replace('\n', '')
        l = line.split()
        print '\n'.join((','.join(x) for x in zip(l[::3], l[1::3], l[2::3])))    
    except:
        print 'error'
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: thanks reply, actually im handling email list.
can i use such like follow style?
maillist = 'scrap_daum.txt'

try:
    handle = open(maillist)
except:
    exit(1)

for line in handle:
    #currline += 1
    valid = []
    try:
        email = line.split(':')[0].replace('\n', '')
    except:
        exit(1)

Comment: hello i was update pastebin site
i want to handle email list

Comment: http://elca.pastebin.com/d4556c585
here is updated site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use csv.writer:

```
import csv
import sys

writer = csv.csvwriter(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(iterable_containing_my_strings)
```

Comment: `iterable_containing_my_strings = open('mail_list.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very specific answer to a very specific question
when you will clarify/generalize your question I may update my answer

```
s = """
uji708
uhodih
utus29
agamu4
azi340
ekon62
"""
l = s.split()
print '\n'.join((','.join(x) for x in zip(l[::3], l[1::3], l[2::3])))
```

Comment: hello thanks for your reply..
can i use some other method?
i was updated pastebin :)
http://elca.pastebin.com/d4556c585